# How to make www-data (Apache) to access Crontab of root in ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, cron

I want to access the root crontab from webpage.How i can do that.I have a project in which i have to list all the jobs on webpage.And after that if needed we need to edit the time for cronjobs configured.

Please help me with this.

Comment: crontab run automatic. Why you run from webpage? I mean, i want to backup mysql data for every Sunday. So, I create a script for backup database. Then, crontab will automatically run every Sunday. If you run from webpage, you refresh you webpage without crontab.

Comment: Yeah i have to show it on webpage because it representing a specific product.You can say i am admin of system and my boss want the track of job running.and if needed want to change the time of execution. @Thiha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use visudo and add

```
`APACHEUSER  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab`
```

APACHEUSER is the user apache runs under like www-data or apache
/usr/bin/crontab is the path to crontab, you can try `which crontab` to find the path

```
<?php
$result = shell_exec('sudo -u root -S crontab -l 2>&1'); // 2>&1 allows you to get stderror
echo $result;

file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $result.'* * * * * /path_to_cron'.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
?
```

Comment: crontab -l from apache directory don't show root crontab.

Comment: your right, try 
    $result = shell_exec('echo "PASS" | sudo -u root -S crontab -l');

Comment: @Brain Keith not not working in shell it's asking for password.

Comment: i just tried this on ubuntu 10.04 use visudo to edit the sudo users add: PHP_USER ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab then you should be able to use: `$result = shell_exec('sudo -u root -S crontab -l 2>&1'); echo $result;`